# Can a single field take multiple queries in elasticsearch, using "multi_match"?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to work with queries in elasticsearch.

```json
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "should":[
        {
          "multi_match":{
            "query":"History",
            "fields":[
              "service_category.keyword"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms":{
            "company_id":[
              "6"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here it is my query.
The result is: All fields that takes `service_category=History` and all `service_category` that have `company_id = 6`.

Now I want to change the result to: All fields that takes `service_category=History` & `company_id=2` also `service_categories` with `company_id = 6`.
I want my answer to be something like :
(service_category.keyword:History AND company_id:2)AND (company_id:6)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could go with:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "History",
                  "fields": [ "service_category.keyword" ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "company_id": [ "2" ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "company_id": [ "6" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which can be understood as:

```sql
(service_category.keyword:History AND company_id:2) OR (company_id:6)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joe!  I've tried this way and it gives me as a result only the service_category with  company_id:6 even though I'm using "must"

Comment: (service_category.keyword:History AND company_id:2) AND(company_id:6) , that is , how I want my answer to be. Sorry for the confusion, I'm new learning elasticsearch

Comment: OK then replace `should` with `must` in my query above.